# Use Java Library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, rhino

I am planning a project where I will develop bots for Agar.io by using the NEAT algorithm, which is implemented in Java (this is called [ANJI](http://anji.sourceforge.net)). I will use the open-source Agar.io server called [Ogar](https://github.com/OgarProject/Ogar), which is implemented in Javascript. The Javascript implementation should communicate with the Java library to evolve the bots while the game is running, but I have no previous experience of how to make Java and Javascript communicate. I have considered using Rhino, but it does not seem like it is possible to use in a browser. So, are there any way to let a Javascript implementation like Ogar use a Java library?

Comment: A quick googling of "nodejs java" turns up [this node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/java). Did you even try to do research?

Answer (score 1):

using the Rhino / Nashorm is not relevant in this case and as for performance focus its should be much hard to run nodeJS based application via Java JS engine.

the  Agar.io server is a NodeJS server that expose a WebSocket API and the client solution need to communicate this way.

[Using spring websocket client for example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-client)

have you seen [Agar.io-bot](https://github.com/Apostolique/Agar.io-bot) ? its seems like the way they implement the BOT is javascript browser extension and communicate via the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In common, Javascript and Java library communicate using Rest and Json, Java provide Rest API and Javascript send Json request to this API.

This is list of java library: for developing [Java Rest API](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links#5-rest-frameworks) and working with [JSON](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links#8--json). I recommend using [RESTEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/).

Comment: That was actually also my initial thought, but then I just kept searching for a solution that could integrate Java and Javascript more tightly. The problem with the Rest/Json-solution is that it might be slower (especially because I need to work with large populations where each agent needs to send a request to the server quite often). But if there is no other way to do it, then I will implement it with the [Play-framework](https://www.playframework.com).